# Showing/Hiding Content-Type Fields Based On User

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I have a content-type that has many fields for different translations. How do I set it up in a way that it shows the translation field based on user selection only. I mean user selects his/her language, then only that content-field appears on the post.

Appreciated...

Comment: I don't think you will have this feature out of the box, why didn't you use the Mutli language features? That'd be the way to go. Otherwise i would just otheride that node template and add some custom code to display only certain field depending on the user preference..

Comment: As I figured, Multi-Language thing is for the entire site. I have different types of data under different content-types, only one content type needs translation.
I think I should set some cookie using PHP code, and based on that I should show one CSS block of translation and hide rest of them, I mean using display:none,  What you think?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you could do that as well, though if you have lot of data hidding things on the server side would be better. You could just override the node template page, with something like :
`node--nodeType.tpl.php`, then in the variables of that page you will have your node with all its Fields available, you can then do a simple check (cookie or sessions) to render appropriate language.

Comment: Thanks, this is good, the unnecessary data does not need to be downloaded just for the browser to hide it.